# Linear Algebra Question about matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If

$ A= \begin{pmatrix}
        -8 &0 &-4 &7 \\
      -2&2&-2&-8\\
7&-8&-1&-1
        \end{pmatrix}$

Then $A_{13}$ is ?

---

I am honestly confused with this question.

---

Comment: We should be clear first about what the notation $A_{13}$ represents.  Usually without further context $A_{i,j}$ represents the entry in matrix $A$ which is in the $i$'th row and the $j$'th column.  In that interpretation, $A_{13}$ is probably intended to be $A_{1,3}$, the entry in the first row and third column.  Now that the definition is out of the way, all that is left is to read your matrix.

Comment: @JMoravitz That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: More context is needed, and I suspect the OP would be able to answer the Question themselves once they checked on that context.  Notation can vary from author to author, but we Readers must depend on the poster to be an expert as to what exactly they are asking.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $A_{13}$ is $A_{ij}$ when $(i,j)=(1,3)$; that is, the entry of the matrix in row $1$ and column $3$. In this case $A_{13}=-4$.